# MacBook not booting up nor recognising bootable usb

Tags: mac, usb, startup, unix

I have this old macbook that I wanted to convert into a ubuntu server, however it didn't recognise my ubuntu server bootable usb which my newer MacBook Air did. After tying to use a 32 bit version and the desktop version it still did not boot. However when I checked the disk utility it did say that the device (usb drive) was attached to the computer. I then started googling and found that pressing cmd+opt+P+R would help so I followed those instructions. But it still didn't help. I tried booting back to the native os but then I got this screen[image: missing operating system]

Can anyone help me so I can at least boot into something. I currently have tried to attach a bootable usb/cd and it would not show up on the boot select when I started up and held the OPT key. This is all that shows up[image: USB drive not showing up]

does anyone know how I can solve this issue? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated